# How to calculate useful upper and lower boundaries for a double value?

Tags: javascript, math

I'm building a realtime chart at the moment. The data, which flows in via WebSockets, basically consists of simple timestamp/value pairs and gets drawn in a time-based line chart. Now I ran into an issue and I wonder what would be the most stable and elegant way:

The chart's Y-scaling has to be dynamic, therefore I have to constantly keep an eye on the min/max values of the visible data. This part is easy as you just have to get the min/max values from the data array and set them as the charts lower and upper limits.

Now I wanted to add some padding to these limit values in order to get nice and round limit values. For example, if the maximum value in the given range is, let's say, `24.7`, I want the upper limit to be `30`. What I need is a function with one parameter that outputs the next upper "nice" value. Here are some examples:

```
     0.13  -->      1
    97.2   -->    100
    17.08  -->     20
   768     -->    800
    -3.4   -->      0
116843     --> 200000
     0.003 -->      0.01
```

Is there a math function that I can use? I definitely need something stable, but I can't see any way to achieve that without starting to count digits and parsing the first digit and so on, which would be very ugly.

Thanks for your help in advance!

Regards,
Rob

PS: I've talked about getting the upper boundary value, I also need a function for the lower boundary, of course, but I guess I can derive that from the function for the upper boundary when we have found a solution.

Comment: No, there's no standard mathematical function for this. For 116,843, what makes 200,000 "nicer" than 120,000?

Comment: Well, it's a matter of taste! ;-) Basically, in natural language, for values above 0 it would have to always increase the first digit value by one and set the rest of the digits to 0. But I want to do that without messing around with .toString() etc.

Comment: I think the numeric algorithms will be messy as well, since you'll need to use base-10 logarithms to find the most significant digit, and then you'll run into floating point approximations.

Comment: Suggest the following as more consistent "0.13 --> 0.2", "-3.4 --> -3" & "0.003 --> 0.003".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take this one (should work for your purpose):

```
function ext_ceil(val){
   if(val < 0)
       return 0;

   var str = val + '';
   var arr = str.split('.');
   var digitsLength = arr[0].length;

   var divisor = 1;
   if(val > 10){

       for(var i=0;i<(digitsLength-1);i++){
           divisor *= 10;
           console.log(divisor);
       }
       val = val / divisor;
       console.log(val);
   }

   val = Math.ceil(val);
   val *= divisor;
   return val;
};
```

if you want to try this algorithm use [my jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Techsolo/48Dcj/)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Your function currently works for values >= 1, but I'll see if I can extend it to support cases like 0.04 --> 0.1 and negative values.

Comment: yes you are right. my mistake. but this can easily been corrected by another `if statement` for lower than 0.1 values you have to find the multiplicator and multiply -> ceil -> divide. For negative values you posted in your examples that -3.4 should be 0. I have understood that negative values should result in 0.

Comment: Sorry, I haven't been precise on this: negative values should behave the same, so that: -17.72 --> -10  and -0.34 --> -0.3. But I'll be able to get this up and running based on your code. I'll post my solution soon. Meanwhile I'm really excited to see if some math cracks come up with some additional magic :-)

Comment: Ok. Thanks. I will be very interested in the complete function ;) (Add ed this as a favorite)